# Scala list take with offset

Tags: list, scala, data-structures

For example I have  `val source = List("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")`
and I need get 3 elements start with second element. expected `List("2","3")` or `List("3","4")`.
Is there any methods or any data structure with this ability?

Comment: "expected `List("2","3")` or `List("3","4")`" - which one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think `slice` is exactly what you're looking for

```
scala> val source = List("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
source: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

scala> source.slice(2, 4)
res0: List[String] = List(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use combinations of `drop` and `take` methods:

```
source.drop(2).take(3) // List(3, 4, 5)
```

- `drop` - skip first `n` elements
- `take` - grab `n` elements

Answer (score 0):

Getting *three elements, starting with second*,

```
source.tail.take(3)
```

which delivers

```
List(2, 3, 4)
```